# Easy way to open a zipped file form FTP directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out an easy and straightforward way of downloading and opening a zipped file, and then loading the contents of this file into a data frame.

I have some code that automatically logs into a FTP directory, and I can find the file I want to download.  I just can't seem to download and unzip this file.  How can I download a zipped file, unzip it, and load the contents into a data frame?

```
user='usr'
password = 'pwd'
ftp = FTP('ftp.corp-site.com', usr, pwd)

locfile = 'C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/' + latest
ftp_path = 'ftp://ftp.corp-site.com/exchangeholidays/' + latest

ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + ftp_path, locfile.write)
```

Thanks for the look.

Comment: I'm having some trouble finding a question in your post.  How far are you getting? What roadblock are you hitting?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working this way:

```
target_dir = 'C:/destination/downloads/'
filematch = latest
for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    target_file_name = os.path.join(target_dir,os.path.basename(filename))
    with open(target_file_name,'wb') as fhandle:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fhandle.write)
```